# UI Application access running on Kubernetes cluster (ROSA - Red Hat OpenShift on AWS) through AWS Cloudfront

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

Nginx server hosts the Node.js Application and running as container inside the Kubernetes POD.

The Kubernetes cluster (ROSA - Red Hat OpenShift on AWS) is running in a private VPC with no internet access. This VPC is connected to on-premise through Direct Connect and Transit Gateway.

The existing traffic flow is as below:

user at on-prem > use Application URL (UI not REST API) in browser > redirects for SAML authentication > after authentication request reaches to R53 Privated Hosted zone > R53 routes the traffic to Classic Load Balancer to the private VPC (where kubernetes cluster is running) > CLB allows the traffic inside Kubernetes cluster.

As part of the cloud migration the locally hosted domain will now be registered as Public domain and traffic will be routed through CloudFront. The CloudFront will replace the on-prem F5 load balancer.

Question: CloudFront is part of AWS Global Network. CloudFront can not distribute traffic to R53 Private Hosted Zone. How can I then send the traffic to the Classic Load Balancer to the private VPC to access the Node.js application hosted by Nginx server running in kubernetes POD?

Please help.

Comment: Consider to ask sys-admin and networking questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.